# Nginx M/Monit password protect

Tags: nginx, port, monit

I am trying to protect access to M/Monit web interface:
**Box:**
ubuntu 14.04
nginx 1.8.1
mmonit-3.5.1

I created a mmonit config file under `/etc/nginx/sites-available`:

```
server {
        listen 8080;
        root /var/www/html;
        location / {
                auth_basic "Restricted Content";
                auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

}
```

It does not display the authentication dialog.
I followed [serverfault-Nginx Password Protect Entire Port Number 8081](https://serverfault.com/questions/620735/nginx-password-protect-entire-port-number-8081), but it seems I am getting something done wrong...I am new to nginx.

Anyone has an idea how to go about it?
Should it be in the same `default` server config file?
Cheers

Comment: Do you include `sites-available` from `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`?

Comment: @uzsolt nope, no need....`include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf; include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;`

Comment: Do you have link to `mmonit.conf` in `sites-enabled`? I think it should work. Maybe you can try to copy your code into `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and check works or not.

Comment: Did you try to include to `/etc/nginx/nginx.comf`? And what about logs? Another trivial thing: do you use port 8080 in your browser? :)

Comment: @uzsolt I don't think the issue is with `nginx`, it's more likely with the configuration. As `M/Monit` is installed from a package, it is not like a website, hence, I could not manage to protect its root folder nor could I protect the port `8080` it's using - with an `Nginx server block`. `nginx` does give an error when I try to protect access to port `8080` - `[emerg] 20526#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:8080 failed (98: Address already in use)`

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out...
(This is under default server config)

```
root /var/www/html/;
server_name localhost;

location /mmonit/ {
    proxy_pass http://yourServerIp:8080/;
    auth_basic "Restricted Content";
    auth_basic_user_file /path/to/your/password/file/;
    index index.csp;
}
```

`ln -s /path/to/your/mmonit/folder/ /var/www/html/`
Gives:
`mmonit -> /path/to/your/mmonit/folder/`

Now point you browser at: `http://yourServerIp/mmonit/`
And you will have the 'Authentication Required' dialog box!
`A username and password are being requested by http://yourServerIp. The site says: "Restricted Content"`

**I do suggest calling the link something else then mmonit....to your choice.
Any wayz your access is now double protected!